# How do I get this project from GitHub?

Tags: github

Microsoft provides sample projects via GitHub, but I've no idea what to do with them.  No instructions are provided.  Here is [the web page](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/ListView/BuiltInCells) for the project.  How do I get the project?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/samples): "To download the code for a specific sample, go to the main page of the relevant Microsoft Github repo and choose either Clone or Download ZIP for the samples."

Comment: The page I linked to does not have a Clone or Download ZIP file.  It has "Go to file" in the top right corner.  I clicked that.  I got to a page that shows the name of a folder and a list of the folders it contains.  There are no instructions on that page.  I guessed that clicking the name of the folder might help.  I got another page that has both "Go to file" and "Code" buttons.  I clicked the Code button and got a drop-down menu that includes "Clone" and "Download ZIP" choices.  

Good grief.

Comment: This is only visible at the root of the repository. [Git supports cloning only part of a repository](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233327/is-it-possible-to-clone-only-part-of-a-git-project), but presumably GitHub didn't find that important to represent in the UI. The normal workflow for Git is to clone the whole repository, not parts of it.

Comment: [Stack Overflow isn't here to replace documentation or tutorials](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/354577). Plug "github tutorial" into the search engine of your choice, pick one or two tutorials that look good (ideally from well-known sources like GitHub itself, GitLab, or Atlassian / Bitbucket), and go through them. Then try to apply what you have learned. If you have _specific_ issues doing this and cannot find existing documentation or SO questions covering your problem, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the [project page](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples)
2. Click on Code
3. Download Zip
4. Once downloaded, extract and navigate the folders to find your sample

[image]